# How to change the Hello World Asterisk example to use TCP instead of UDP?

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip, pjsip

I setup Asterisk on a server. 
I set up the basic "Hello, World" example (direct from the docs [here](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Hello+World)) which entails having my `extensions.conf` file as:

```
[from-internal]
exten = 100,1,Answer()
same = n,Wait(1)
same = n,Playback(hello-world)
same = n,Hangup()
```

and my `pjsip.conf` file as:

```
[transport-udp]
type=transport
protocol=udp
bind=0.0.0.0

[6001]
type=endpoint
context=from-internal
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
auth=6001
aors=6001

[6001]
type=auth
auth_type=userpass
password=unsecurepassword
username=6001

[6001]
type=aor
max_contacts=1
```

I have a simple Python script to make a call to the extension 100. This is direct from the docs [here](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Python_SIP/Hello_World), where I call this script passing in the sip address `sip:100@<my-sip-server-ip>`:

```
import sys
import pjsua as pj

# Logging callback
def log_cb(level, str, len):
    print str,

# Callback to receive events from Call
class MyCallCallback(pj.CallCallback):
    def __init__(self, call=None):
        pj.CallCallback.__init__(self, call)

    # Notification when call state has changed
    def on_state(self):
        print "Call is ", self.call.info().state_text,
        print "last code =", self.call.info().last_code, 
        print "(" + self.call.info().last_reason + ")"

    # Notification when call's media state has changed.
    def on_media_state(self):
        global lib
        if self.call.info().media_state == pj.MediaState.ACTIVE:
            # Connect the call to sound device
            call_slot = self.call.info().conf_slot
            lib.conf_connect(call_slot, 0)
            lib.conf_connect(0, call_slot)
            print "Hello world, I can talk!"


# Check command line argument
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print "Usage: simplecall.py <dst-URI>"
    sys.exit(1)

try:
    # Create library instance
    lib = pj.Lib()

    # Init library with default config
    lib.init(log_cfg = pj.LogConfig(level=3, callback=log_cb))

    # Create UDP transport which listens to any available port
    transport = lib.create_transport(pj.TransportType.UDP)

    # Start the library
    lib.start()

    # Create local/user-less account
    acc = lib.create_account_for_transport(transport)

    # Make call
    call = acc.make_call(sys.argv[1], MyCallCallback())

    # Wait for ENTER before quitting
    print "Press <ENTER> to quit"
    input = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip("\r\n")

    # We're done, shutdown the library
    lib.destroy()
    lib = None

except pj.Error, e:
    print "Exception: " + str(e)
    lib.destroy()
    lib = None
    sys.exit(1)
```

This all works fine, I call the SIP server, and hear the "Hello, World" recording.

**What do I need to change so that I can have this communication occur over TCP?**
So far I have tried changing my `pjsip.conf` file by changing the protocol to tcp in the following part:

```
[transport-udp]
type=transport
protocol=udp
bind=0.0.0.0
```

, adding `;transport=tcp` to the URI of my server that I pass in to the Python script, and also changing the line in the Python script that creates a Transport to

```
# Create UDP transport which listens to any available port
transport = lib.create_transport(pj.TransportType.UDP)
```

What happens is in the Python script I get

```
pjsua_acc.c !...SIP registration failed, status=408 (Request Timeout)
```

And on the server I don't see the request at all.

Comment: Check this link: https://www.linuxsysadmintutorials.com/using-sip-over-tcp-with-asterisk -> maybe useful

Comment: This is basic network troubleshooting. First, packet trace on your client to ensure that it's even communicating. Then check firewalls on the server side.

Comment: Also, this is probably just a typo in your question, but you say you are changing the Transport to UDP, but then list the same lines again:

# Create UDP transport which listens to any available port
transport = lib.create_transport(pj.TransportType.UDP)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your Asterisk is using pjsip? Old versions (below v.11) are using sip.conf and not pjsip.conf.

You need to enable tcp globally in **sip.conf**:

```
[general]
tcpenable=yes
tcpbindaddr=0.0.0.0
```

If you are on a new Asterisk, then add this to **pjsip.conf**:

```
[transport-tcp]
type=transport
protocol=tcp
bind=0.0.0.0:5060

[transport-tcp-out]
type=transport
protocol=tcp
bind=0.0.0.0:5060
#local_net=192.168.X.X/XX   //you might also set this
```